# SQL Query Error in Group By and Order By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting chat messages of a user from two tables so I use an `inner join` to this. Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT  
    m.Message_Id 
    , m.Chat_Relation_Id AS relation_id 
    , m.SenderId AS datetime 
    , m.Text_Message 
    , m.Subject 
    , m.DateTime
FROM  
    [AppResource].[dbo].[ChatMessage] AS m  
    INNER JOIN [AppResource].[dbo].[chatRelation] AS r 
    ON r.Chat_Relation_Id = m.Chat_Relation_Id 
WHERE  
    r.User1Id=1 
GROUP BY 
    m.Chat_Relation_Id 
ORDER BY  
    m.DateTime DESC
```

But when I am running this, I am getting the following error message:

> Column 'AppResource.dbo.ChatMessage.Message_Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have searched a lot on google and found many solutions but nothing works. `Text_Message` is  of `text` datatype and `DateTime` is of `Datetime` datatype.

Please help me in it.

```
Message_Id  relation_id datetime    Text_Message    Subject DateTime
4   1   2   Hello   Hi  2014-11-25 00:00:00.000
8   25  1   hiii    ho  2014-03-26 09:07:27.000
7   26  1       hiiiiii 2014-03-26 07:07:27.000
6   25  1       hi  2014-03-26 07:01:58.000
```

Comment: Well - you cannot select something which is not a part of the group by clause or an aggregate function - when using group by. And Message_Id is not a part of your group by nor an aggregate function. (And neither are a number of your other columns in the select)

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: But when I add all the columns coming in select then it gives an error of text datatype. Can you please tell me how should it be done?

Comment: You cannot group by a `text` column. You may want to cast it `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)` and group like that. Adding all the columns to `group by` will probably result in no grouping at all though... I'm just guessing as I do not know your data.

Comment: @Szymon: I am making a chat system. I have one table chatRelation with a Chat_Relation_id/User1Id/User2Id and another Table ChatMessage with Message_Id(AI)/Chat_Relation_Id/Sender_Id/Subject/Message/DateTime. So I am trying to fetch all the matches of a user on the basis of his relation ids with other users.

Comment: Don't use `text` - it's deprecated and has issue - like this one here (you cannot group on it). Use `varchar(max)` if you **really** need to support up to 2 **billion** characters for each message - or use something more reasonable, like `varchar(200)` or whatever (Twitter is 140 characters, after all - and that seems to be sufficient for most chats and tweets....)

Comment: Uh, what are you grouping for?

Comment: This is the main question. There is zero sense in this grouping to start with as it seems. There is no way to group and then - have what texts there? I think the whole query is bonkers from the way it is formulated and the OP tries to achieve something in the totally wrong way - i.e. it should be done without grouping, or it should not contain the message text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `GROUP BY` you will normally have [aggregate functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx), the SQL you provided does not actually have any aggregate functions in it so there's no need for it to be grouped.

```
SELECT  
    m.Message_Id 
    , m.Chat_Relation_Id AS relation_id 
    , m.SenderId AS datetime 
    , m.Text_Message 
    , m.Subject 
    , m.DateTime
FROM  
    [AppResource].[dbo].[ChatMessage] AS m  
    INNER JOIN [AppResource].[dbo].[chatRelation] AS r 
    ON r.Chat_Relation_Id = m.Chat_Relation_Id 
WHERE  
    r.User1Id=1 
GROUP BY 
    m.Chat_Relation_Id 
ORDER BY  
    m.DateTime desc
```

The error is being thrown because all non aggregate columns must be defined in the `GROUP BY` clause as this defines how the other (aggregate) columns are calculated. In your instance and given the problem described, I'm guessing just removing the `GROUP BY` will resolve your problem.

```
SELECT  
    m.Message_Id 
    , m.Chat_Relation_Id AS relation_id 
    , m.SenderId AS datetime 
    , m.Text_Message 
    , m.Subject 
    , m.DateTime
FROM  
    [AppResource].[dbo].[ChatMessage] AS m  
    INNER JOIN [AppResource].[dbo].[chatRelation] AS r 
    ON r.Chat_Relation_Id = m.Chat_Relation_Id 
WHERE  
    r.User1Id = 1 
ORDER BY  
    m.DateTime DESC
```

**Edit after comment regarding duplicated entries:**

The following query will get the most recent entry for each `Chat_Relation_Id`

```
SELECT  
    m.Chat_Relation_Id AS relation_id 
    , MAX(m.DateTime) AS maxDateTime
FROM  
    [AppResource].[dbo].[ChatMessage] AS m  
    INNER JOIN [AppResource].[dbo].[chatRelation] AS r 
    ON r.Chat_Relation_Id = m.Chat_Relation_Id 
WHERE  
    r.User1Id = 1 
GROUP BY 
    m.Chat_Relation_Id
```

This is far from ideal, but could be used as a sub query to select the relevant text as follows:

```
SELECT  
    m.Message_Id 
    , m.Chat_Relation_Id AS relation_id 
    , m.SenderId AS datetime 
    , m.Text_Message 
    , m.Subject 
    , m.DateTime
FROM  
    (SELECT  
        subqueryMessage.Chat_Relation_Id AS relation_id 
        , MAX(subqueryMessage.DateTime) AS maxDateTime
    FROM  
        [AppResource].[dbo].[ChatMessage] AS subqueryMessage  
        INNER JOIN [AppResource].[dbo].[chatRelation] AS subQueryRelation 
        ON subQueryRelation.Chat_Relation_Id = subqueryMessage.Chat_Relation_Id 
    WHERE  
        subQueryRelation.User1Id = 1 
    GROUP BY 
        subqueryMessage.Chat_Relation_Id 
    ) AS mySubQuery
    INNER JOIN [AppResource].[dbo].[ChatMessage] AS m  
    ON  m.Chat_Relation_Id = mySubQuery.relation_id
        AND m.DateTime = mySubQuery.maxDateTime
ORDER BY  
    m.DateTime DESC
```

I don't like using sub-queries like this but I'm a developer not a DBA, and the above is limited such that if there are items with identical `Chat_Relation_Id` and `DateTime` then duplicates will still occur. There is probably a clever way of doing it using a [`HAVING` Clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php) but hopefully if this doesn't give you something to work from it will help someone else resolve your problem.

Comment: But your edited query will give duplicate results for Chat_Relation_Id. I want only recent entry corresponding to each Chat_Relation_Id. How can I modify that?

Comment: What are you actually trying to return? It might be worth updating your question with either a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or detailed data structure, and what you are trying to return with the results, I think I have an idea and will post it when I work it out but you'll probably get more help (including from other members) if you provide more detailed requirements in your question.

Comment: I have updated my question for you. Please look over it. There are multiple entries for Chat_Relation_Id but with different DateTime. So, what all I want only top most Row for each Chat_Relation_Id i.e. latest chat message for each relation id.

Comment: I already updated my answer, hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.