# Group By in SQL Statement Not Grouping as Expected

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I'm looking for some help with the below statement. My intention is to group the results by `dom.OutcomeType` to only return two records in the result set (also below). The reason there's so many grouping criteria is because I'm using Access 2007 and it insists on having every returned value in the group by statement.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT d.DiagnosticId, d.AbsenceId, dqm.QuestionNumber, dq.Question, dqm.AnswerId, dom.OutcomeType, do.Outcome, d.AcceptedId, d.Reason
FROM (((ct_adt_Diag d
    INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagOMatch dom ON d.DiagnosticId = dom.DiagnosticId)
    INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagOutcome do ON dom.OutcomeId = do.OutcomeId)
    INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagQAMatch dqm ON d.DiagnosticId = dqm.DIagnosticId)
    INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagQuestion dq ON dqm.QuestionId = dq.QuestionId
WHERE d.AbsenceId = 19
GROUP BY dom.OutcomeType, d.DiagnosticId, d.AbsenceId, dq.Question, dqm.AnswerId, dqm.QuestionNumber, do.Outcome, d.AcceptedId, d.Reason
ORDER BY d.DiagnosticId, dqm.QuestionNumber
```

**Results**
[image: Results]

Thanks

Comment: As you're not using an aggregate function, why are you using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: In SQL/RA (it's not just Access!), if there is a GROUP BY then every output column *must* be specified in the grouping or in an aggregate function - or the query simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Its not just ACCESS but any DBMS will have you do that.. All non-aggregare columns have to be in the Group by Clause

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655648/sql-query-error-in-group-by-and-order-by-clause/22658161#22658161) helpful as it goes into using a `GROUP BY` in a sub-query to limit the results returned. You seem to have completely misunderstood the usage of [GROUP BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php) and probably should be considering how you would want to aggregate your results.

Comment: What leads you to suspect that there are more records ("only return two records")?  What happens when you run  Select * From ct_adt_Diag d Where d.AbsenceId = 19 ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
GROUP BY dom.OutcomeType, d.DiagnosticId, d.AbsenceId, dq.Question, dqm.AnswerId, dqm.QuestionNumber, do.Outcome, d.AcceptedId, d.Reason
```

with

```
GROUP BY dom.OutcomeType
```

Comment: With an appropriate aggregate over the remaining columns, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You are requested to add all these fields to the GROUP BY clause, because Access treats your whole query as an aggregate query. You can either split your query into two queries or do it altogether in one messy statement as follows:

```
SELECT d.DiagnosticId, d.AbsenceId, dqm.QuestionNumber, dq.Question, dqm.AnswerId, 
dom.OutcomeType, do.Outcome, d.AcceptedId, d.Reason
FROM (((ct_adt_Diag As d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dom.OutcomeType
    FROM ct_adt_DiagOMatch As dom
    GROUP BY dom.OutcomeType
) ON d.DiagnosticId = dom.DiagnosticId)
INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagOutcome do ON dom.OutcomeId = do.OutcomeId)
INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagQAMatch dqm ON d.DiagnosticId = dqm.DIagnosticId)
INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagQuestion dq ON dqm.QuestionId = dq.QuestionId
WHERE d.AbsenceId = 19
ORDER BY d.DiagnosticId, dqm.QuestionNumber
```

I hope I am not missing any parenthesis!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like this...

I dont know your data but this should get you started in that direction.

```
    WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT d.DiagnosticId
        , MIn(d.AbsenceId) AbsenceId
        , MIN(dqm.QuestionNumber) QuestionNumber
        , MIN(dq.Question) Question
        , MIN(dqm.AnswerId) AnswerId
        , MIN(dom.OutcomeType) OutcomeType
        , MIN(do.Outcome) Outcome
        , MIn(d.AcceptedId) AcceptedId
        , MIN(d.Reason) Reason
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY dom.OutcomeType ORDER BY d.DiagnosticId,, dqm.QuestionNumber
            ) rownum
    FROM (
        (
            (
                ct_adt_Diag d INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagOMatch dom
                    ON d.DiagnosticId = dom.DiagnosticId
                ) INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagOutcome do
                ON dom.OutcomeId = do.OutcomeId
            ) INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagQAMatch dqm
            ON d.DiagnosticId = dqm.DIagnosticId
        )
    INNER JOIN ct_adt_DiagQuestion dq
        ON dqm.QuestionId = dq.QuestionId
    WHERE d.AbsenceId = 19
    GROUP BY dom.OutcomeType
        , d.DiagnosticId    
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum <= 2
```