# PostgreSQL: GROUP BY and ORDER BY, whole dataset as a result

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgres database I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID (Pimary Key)
Code
Date
```

I'm trying to extract data ordered by Date and grouped by Code so that the most recent date will determine what code rows should be grouped first and so forth (if it makes sense). An example:

```
007    2022-01-04
007    2022-01-01
007    2021-12-19
002    2022-01-03
002    2021-12-02
002    2021-11-15
035    2022-01-01
035    2021-11-30
035    2021-05-03
001    2021-12-31
022    2021-12-07
076    2021-11-19
```

I thought I could achieve this with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
GROUP BY Table.Code
ORDER BY Table.Date DESC
```

but this gives me

```
ERROR:  column "Table.ID" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

And if I add the column ID to the GROUP BY the result I get is just a list ordered by Date with all the Codes mixed.

Is there any way to achieve whai I want?

Comment: You can't use * in a ``group by`` select. You should use select ``Table.Code``, .... The same situation is in ``order by`` clause. You can order only ``Table.Code`` and grouped columns (max, count, ...).

Comment: Try: `SELECT Table.Code, max(Table.Date) FROM Table GROUP BY Table.Code ORDER BY max(Table.Date) DESC`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql-query-error-in-group-by-and-order-by-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655648/sql-query-error-in-group-by-and-order-by-clause)?

Comment: @DavidLukas Sorry I've used * just to say 'all columns'. Anyway I've tried what you suggest and I get the same old error: it seems it wants the primary key in the ORDER BY?

Comment: @DavidLukas No the link doesn't answer my question unfortunately as I don't have two tables to join. I've tried with subqueries but I still have the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit 3

More elegant solution using `max over partition by`.

```
SELECT
"Code",
"Date"
FROM
"Table"
ORDER BY
 max("Date") over (partition by "Code") DESC,
 "Table"."Date" DESC
;
```

Output:

| Code | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 007 | 2022-01-04T00:00:00Z |
| 007 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 007 | 2021-12-19T00:00:00Z |
| 002 | 2022-01-03T00:00:00Z |
| 002 | 2021-12-02T00:00:00Z |
| 002 | 2021-11-15T00:00:00Z |
| 035 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 035 | 2021-11-30T00:00:00Z |
| 035 | 2021-05-03T00:00:00Z |
| 001 | 2021-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| 022 | 2021-12-07T00:00:00Z |
| 076 | 2021-11-19T00:00:00Z |

### Edit 2:

I join a select `b` with the entire dataset. The select `b` is used for sort only and is what you tried.

```
With "b" as
( select
   "Code",
    max("Date") as "Date"
  from
   "Table"
  group by
   "Code"
)
SELECT
 "Table"."Code",
 "Table"."Date"
FROM
"Table" left join "b" on "Table"."Code" = "b"."Code"
ORDER BY
 "b"."Date" desc,
 "Table"."Date" DESC;
```

Output:

| Code | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 007 | 2022-01-04T00:00:00Z |
| 007 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 007 | 2021-12-19T00:00:00Z |
| 002 | 2022-01-03T00:00:00Z |
| 002 | 2021-12-02T00:00:00Z |
| 002 | 2021-11-15T00:00:00Z |
| 035 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 035 | 2021-11-30T00:00:00Z |
| 035 | 2021-05-03T00:00:00Z |
| 001 | 2021-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| 022 | 2021-12-07T00:00:00Z |
| 076 | 2021-11-19T00:00:00Z |

### Edit1

A `group by` clause should contain a unique value per line.

The example below show a way to fix the error on your data.

Table with ID:

```
CREATE TABLE "Table" (
     "ID" serial not null primary key,
     "Code" varchar,
     "Date" timestamp
);

INSERT INTO "Table"
    ("Code", "Date")
VALUES
    ('007', '2022-01-04 00:00:00'),
    ('007', '2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('007', '2021-12-19 00:00:00'),
    ('002', '2022-01-03 00:00:00'),
    ('002', '2021-12-02 00:00:00'),
    ('002', '2021-11-15 00:00:00'),
    ('035', '2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('035', '2021-11-30 00:00:00'),
    ('035', '2021-05-03 00:00:00'),
    ('001', '2021-12-31 00:00:00'),
    ('022', '2021-12-07 00:00:00'),
    ('076', '2021-11-19 00:00:00')
;
```

Select:

```
SELECT * FROM "Table" ORDER BY "Code", "Date" DESC;
```

Output:

| ID | Code | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 001 | 2021-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| 4 | 002 | 2022-01-03T00:00:00Z |
| 5 | 002 | 2021-12-02T00:00:00Z |
| 6 | 002 | 2021-11-15T00:00:00Z |
| 1 | 007 | 2022-01-04T00:00:00Z |
| 2 | 007 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 3 | 007 | 2021-12-19T00:00:00Z |
| 11 | 022 | 2021-12-07T00:00:00Z |
| 7 | 035 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 8 | 035 | 2021-11-30T00:00:00Z |
| 9 | 035 | 2021-05-03T00:00:00Z |
| 12 | 076 | 2021-11-19T00:00:00Z |

### Original Answer

First, select the columns that you want to group e.g. `Code`, that you want to apply an aggregate function (`Date`).
Second, list the columns that you want to group in the GROUP BY clause.
In the `order by` clause, use the same logic as the `select` clause.

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Table"
    ("Code" int, "Date" timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO "Table"
    ("Code", "Date")
VALUES
    (007, '2022-01-04 00:00:00'),
    (007, '2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (007, '2021-12-19 00:00:00'),
    (002, '2022-01-03 00:00:00'),
    (002, '2021-12-02 00:00:00'),
    (002, '2021-11-15 00:00:00'),
    (035, '2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (035, '2021-11-30 00:00:00'),
    (035, '2021-05-03 00:00:00'),
    (001, '2021-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (022, '2021-12-07 00:00:00'),
    (076, '2021-11-19 00:00:00')
;
```

Select

```
SELECT
  "Table"."Code",
   max("Table"."Date")
FROM
  "Table"
GROUP BY
  "Table"."Code"
ORDER BY
  max("Table"."Date") DESC
```

Output:

| Code | max |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 2022-01-04T00:00:00Z |
| 2 | 2022-01-03T00:00:00Z |
| 35 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 1 | 2021-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| 22 | 2021-12-07T00:00:00Z |
| 76 | 2021-11-19T00:00:00Z |

Comment: No this isn't right: first of all your table is missing the ID column as Primary Key (which is the column that creates the issue) but also in your output you're leaving out 2 rows for code 007, 002 and 035: I have to show the whole data set

Comment: @FleaLes If you need `group by Code` then there will be only one Code per line. It is what `group by` does. If you need one `ID` per row and multiple Codes then you don't need `group by Code`.

Comment: @FleaLes Review my answer, especially Edit 2.

Comment: Yes, Edit 2 and the more elegant Edit 3 work brilliantly. Thanks.